# Captura de imagens simultaneamente em duas câmeras USB em intervalos regulares no Android

Tags: android, timer, android-camera

Olá gostaria de algumas dicas de como desenvolver no Android um aplicativo para captura de fotos simultâneas em intervalos regulares, de duas câmeras USB (Câmera MJPEG M12 Lente AR0330 Dupla Estéreo Micro Mini Módulo de Câmera Industrial USB 2.0 Driverless para 3D VR Aplicação) através um Timer simples, como por exemplo: a cada 60 segundos capturar 6 imagens.

Comment: Olá, boas vindas ao SO! Por favor detalhe sua pergunta. Com mais informações fica mais fácil de auxiliarmos você. São um começo aspectos como o tipo de aplicação (se é um app ou serviço), modelo da câmera, protocolos de comunicação, etc.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, acredito que agora esteja mais claro e objetivo

Comment: Então, de forma resumida, teu objetivo é criar um aplicativo de câmera que suporte a captura simultânea de duas imagens com timer, correto?

Comment: sim, exatamente isso !

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que essencialmente o seu objetivo é desenvolver um aplicativo de câmera, começamos pelas referências de utilização de câmeras externas no desenvolvimento para Android. O SDK do sistema tem suporte ao uso de câmeras USB, como explicado [neste artigo](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) (em inglês).

Você precisa utilizar a API [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) para ler a stream da câmera, e ao mesmo tempo pode exibir esse stream em uma `SurfaceView` e, de acordo com a sua necessidade, fazer as capturas usando os mesmos métodos dessa API. Acredito que os tutoriais relacionados à API mencionada devem ser suficientes para que você consiga implementar essa funcionalidade. [Este tutorial do Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media) tem algumas referências interessantes.

Com relação à temporização, existem diversas formas de implementar. Você pode ter um serviço/alarme que, quando disparado, inicia o app de câmera, que por sua vez executa uma captura e se fecha automaticamente. Ou, por exemplo, manter o app aberto e em sua instância, um timer que faça esse controle. Note que em ambos os casos será necessário manter a tela do celular sempre ligada, assim você provavelmente precisará de permissões extras, como a `WAKE_LOCK`.